# Is there anyway to test sorting functionality of a web table in either Selenium Webdriver or Katalon Studio?

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, katalon-studio

Is it possible to test the sorting functionality of a web table in Katalon Studio/Selenium Webdriver? 
Does Katalon Studio/Selenium Webdriver have any default method to verify whether the datas within a single column is either in ascending or descending order?

The following is the code that I used to fetch all the values listed in the 1st column of a web table and save them in an array:

```
WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()

'To locate table'

WebElement Table = driver.findElement(By.xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]'))



'To locate rows of table it will Capture all the rows available in the table'

List<WebElement> rows_table = Table.findElements(By.tagName('tr'))



'To calculate no of rows In table'

int rows_count = rows_table.size()



String[] celltext = new String[rows_count]

for (int row = 0; row < rows_count; row++) {

'To locate columns(cells) of that specific row'

List<WebElement> Columns_row = rows_table.get(row).findElements(By.tagName('td'))

'It will retrieve text from 1st cell'

String celltext_1 = Columns_row.get(0).getText()

celltext[row] = celltext_1

}
```

For example, celltext = [4,3,2,1]
Now I want to verify that the values saved in celltext is in descending order.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: No there are no ready mate method for that , you have to write it explicitly. That'd be easy to I guess !

Answer (score 2):

Neither selenium nor katalon provides sorting functionality. But you can use java Arrays utility class to sort the items and compare it as follows.

```
String[] celltextBefore = celltext;

Arrays.sort(celltext, Collections.reverseOrder());

if(Arrays.equals(celltextBefore, celltext))
{
   System.out.println("Celltext is in descending order");
}
else{
   System.out.println("Celltext is not in descending order");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick feedback @murthi. I have used the above code and got the following error unfortunately:


java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$ReverseComparator cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to Murthi for giving me the splendid idea of comparing arrays.

The following way I was able to solve my problem:

```
    List<Integer> celltext_list = Arrays.asList(celltext);
    Collections.sort(celltext_list, Collections.reverseOrder());
    int[] celltext_new = celltext_list.toArray();

    if(Arrays.equals(celltext_new, celltext)){
        System.out.println("Celltext is in descending order")
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Celltext is in ascending order")
    }
```

In Murthi's solution above, there was an error throwing which I added to his comment. Finally came up with the above solution.